# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que mi Spinner muestre la lista pero no permita seleccionar los elementos?

Tags: android

Estoy realizando esta app para android. La idea es que cuando el usuario clicke un nombre (que es un `spinner`) se despliegue una listilla con info (edad, equipo, etc). Sin embargo dicha info sería solo para VER no para seleccionar. Por default, un `spinner` hace que dicha info se pueda seleccionar. ¿Hay algo que pueda hacer para lograr mi propósito? Este es el código:

**MainActivity.xml**

```
    <Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/mySpinner"
    android:background="@color/Artes"
    android:popupBackground="@color/Artes"
```

**Mainactivity.java**

```
public class NacionalInicial extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nacional_inicial);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //método Spinner

    Spinner arquitecturaNacional = (Spinner) findViewById(mySpinner);

    ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(NacionalInicial.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names));
    myAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    arquitecturaNacional.setAdapter(myAdapter);

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Para deshabilitarlo y no permitir su despliegue se usa la propiedad:

```
spinner.setEnabled(false);
```

---

Para que se desplieguen los valores en la lista pero no permita dar clic a los elementos, puedes deshabilitar la acción mediante el listener `OnTouchListener` retornando un valor `false` al dar clic :

```
spinner.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
{      
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
    {      
        return false;
    }

});
```

o simplemente usando la propiedad:

```
spinner.setClickable(false);
```

Comment: La propiedad:                                                                                                           spinner.setClickable(false); 
se pone dentro del método void onCreate? Lo pregunto porque al hacerlo aparece que android "no reconoce el símbolo

Comment: en tu caso es despues  de definir el spinner, pero tiene otro nombre, sería arquitecturaNacional.setClickable(false); @saeta